# Start with empty list, create a list of size 3, and then add more values and create another list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have an expression inside a list:

```
l = [['h'], '+', ['c'], '-', ['d'], '+', [['e'], '-', ['f'], '+', ['y']], '+', ['a']]
```

I want to build an expression in a binary format by creating lists of size 3 until the entire original list has been iterated. This means that if any nested lists of lists exist, I have to traverse them as well.
This would be the result:

```
final_list = [[[[['h'], '+', ['c']], '-', ['d']], '+', [[['e'], '-', ['f']], '+', ['y']]], '+', ['a']]
```

I have tried:

```
count = 0
def make_list(l):
    final_list = []
    temp_list = []
    for index, value in enumerate(l):
        count += 1
        if len(value) == 1 or (value == '+' or value == '-'):
            temp_list.append(value)
        elif len(value) != 1:
            final_list.append(make_list(l[index]))
        if count == 3:
            final_list.append(temp_list[:])
            temp_list.clear()
            count = 1
    return final_list
```

The problem with this code is that it adds new lists from temp_list, so the resulting answer is like this:

```
[[[[['h'], '+', ['c']], ['-', ['d']], '+', [[['e'], '-', ['f']], '+', ['y']], '+', ['a']]]
```

EDIT:
MYousefi's solution works for any expression as long as it is not size 3. But when an expression of size 3 like this is inputted:

```
[['b'], '+', [['c'], '-', ['d'], '+', ['e']]]
```

Then his solution does not access and create a list of size 3 continuously inside the nested list.

Comment: Quick tip: move `final_list = []` to inside of the function definition

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive definition:

```
def make_list(l):
    if isinstance(l, str) or len(l) <= 3:
        return l
    return [make_list(l[:-2]), make_list(l[-2]), make_list(l[-1])]
```

Comment: I have a question regarding the code, if the length of the list is size 3, but one of the lists inside of the code is not size 3, then it will not subdivide the list into size 3. Example: [['b'], '+', [['a'], '+', [['c'], '-', ['d], '+', ['e']]]] This will not subdivide the list continuously into size 3. How can the code be changed to do this?

Comment: How should such a case be handled? It is possible to handle those cases but there's no rule for it in the original problem.